# How to print result in one line

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to solve a problem with this code:

```
equipoa = input("Digite las iniciales del equipo a: ")
equipob = input("Digite las iniciales del equipo b: ")

anotadores = input("Digite los anotadores del partido:")

equipoa = equipoa.upper()
equipob = equipob.upper()
anotadores = anotadores.upper()

print(equipoa)
print(equipob)

contadora = 0
contadorb = 0


for letra in anotadores:
    if letra in equipoa:
        contadora += 1
    else:
        contadorb += 1
    
    if contadora > contadorb:
        print("X")
    elif contadorb > contadora:
        print("Y")
    else:
        print("Z")
```

The output for it is:

```
X
Z
X
Z
X
Z
```

but I need it horizontal:

```
XZXZXZ
```

. I tried to put it into a list and print it, but it didn't concatenate.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `end` parameter of a `print()` statement so that it does not emit a new line:

```
if contadora > contadorb:
    print("X", end="")
elif contadorb > contadora:
    print("Y", end="")
else:
    print("Z", end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just solve it, making a list wit a join:

```
equipoa = input("Digite las iniciales del equipo a: ")
equipob = input("Digite las iniciales del equipo b: ")

anotadores = input("Digite los anotadores del partido:")

equipoa = equipoa.upper()
equipob = equipob.upper()
anotadores = anotadores.upper()

print(equipoa)
print(equipob)

contadora = 0
contadorb = 0

list = []

for letra in anotadores:
    if letra in equipoa:
        contadora += 1
    else:
        contadorb += 1
    
    if contadora > contadorb:
        list.append("X")
        
    elif contadorb > contadora:
        list.append("Y")
    else:
        list.append("Z")

str = "".join(list)
print(str)
```

Maybe it works for someone.